# set 2 characters as one

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I have a TextView(bt) containing two strings..

```
bt.setText("\u06AD" + ":");
```

I want to consider this two strings as one and when I hit the delete button, both should be clear.
How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If `bt` is a `TextView`, why don't you call `bt.setText("");` when the delete button is hit?

Comment: It is a TextView but with different buttons.
When one of the buttons hits, a character add to the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

```
bt.setText("");
```

Or what you are meaning?:)